# Did contemporary sources mention the Muslim victory over the Roman Empire?

Tags: islam

During the reign of Umar (second Caliph of Islam), the Eastern Roman Empire was taken over by Muslims. Since, at that time, the Roman empire was vast, the news should have surely reached other parts of the Roman empire specially the central part. My question is, is there mention of this event in the books/records/letters of Romans of that time ?

Comment: Hi Noor. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: You should explain what you mean by the "Roman Empire" being taken over. Although the Eastern Roman (aka [Byzantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire)) Empire lost a lot of territory (especially Egypt) during this time, the empire lasted in one form or another until 1453. The Western (Rome-based) part of the empire fell well before this time, so the Byzantines called themselves "Romans" until the end.

Comment: @sempaiscuba, I did do some research on google, but getting mostly articles and not mentioning the original sources

Comment: At the time of Umar, the Eastern Roman Empire was the *only* Roman Empire. Umar conquered huge swathes of Byzantine territories in the Levant and in Africa, but did not actually "take over" the ERE as a whole - the Empire persisted for almost another millennium. I presume you're really asking about Byzantine sources mentioning the Muslims? I can't imagine there's a paucity of records on Islam in general even in this period, so I would suggest you select a particular battle, campaign, or conquest to focus on source requests for.

Comment: @Semaphore unless they all burned up in 1204.

Comment: If I may add to an earlier point.  Although the Byzantines lost nearly all of their colonial territories in the Middle East and North Africa during the Early Middle Ages, the Byzantine Empire's colonial territories were mostly confined to the Balkan region, parts of the Black Sea region, as well as the Eastern Italian coast-(though to a lesser extent).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many primary sources, here is a list: https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/sbook1d.asp#Islamic Expansion and Empires - to 750 CE